# Unable to find a converter that supports conversion to/from string for the property of type 'Type'

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I'm writing a custom config class in C# and .NET 3.5. One of the properties should be of type System.Type. When I run the code I get the error mentioned in the title.

```
[ConfigurationProperty("alertType", IsRequired = true)]
public Type AlertType
{
    get { return (Type)this["alertType"]; }
    set { this["alertType"] = value; }
}
```

The config file looks like this:

```
<add name="Name" pollingInterval="60" alertType="Namespace.ClassName, Company.Project" />
```

The .net framework is able to cast a string into System.Type, because the configSections of the config file has a type attribute. The question is how do they do it.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I know this is old, but I think this is actually the correct answer:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(TypeNameConverter))]
[ConfigurationProperty("alertType", IsRequired=true)]
public Type AlertType
{
    get { return this[ "alertType" ] as Type; }
    set { this[ "alertType" ] = value; }
}
```

Adding the TypeNameConverter makes the transformation from String to Type happen without using Type.GetType().

Comment: Yeah, the accepted solution didn't work for me for some reason, whereas this did.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for [Type.GetType Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx)

Comment: Sometimes we try to look too hard and the answer is right in front of us :)

Answer (score 5):

You can try using the [TypeNameConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.typenameconverter.aspx) class. It has two methods you may be interested in:

`ConvertToString` and `ConvertFromString`